What is Richter Mode for in Dead Cells?
In Dead Cells, I recently tried out Richter Mode for the first time, had a couple heart attacks when I realised how little health I had (don’t worry, I’m fine), and then a couple more heart attacks when I died and thought that was the end of the run (again, I’m fine).
The movement was vaguely annoying though, and I don’t really want to go through that again, and the answers to the following questions will help me decide if I end up doing it anyway.
What’s the end goal of Richter Mode (I assume to kill Dracula as Richter)? What do I get for beating it?

And regarding your second heart attack...

It's a game mode with a fixed map that has the only purpose of finding Alucard's Sword blueprint:

You have to reach the end and defeat the boss in order to unlock it.
As a bonus, the first time you complete Richter mode you will also unlock Richter's outfit.
